# Same variable importance scores for SVM, KNN, and NB classifiers (R CARET )

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, caret

I am comparing some ML classifiers (RF, KNN, SVM, NB, and XGBOOST). After training these classifiers, I extracted variable importance scores from each of these models using varImp function in CARET.

I noticed that the variable importance scores for SVM, KNN, and NB are exactly the same. I am wondering, how is this possible.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the fact that these are methods where no built-in importance score is implemented and the default behaviour to estimate importance is to compute the area under the ROC curve for each predictor. It is better explained at ch. 15 of the documentation  "The `caret` package" at https://topepo.github.io/caret/.

Comment: Thanks a lot autu_mn. This was very helpful.